# align-like environment in LaTeX for lines of texts

Tags: latex

I am looking for a LaTeX environment, that is capable of formatting given paragraph(s) with a slight indentation and increasing line counters within parenthesis, e.g.:

> (1) Lorem Ipsum
>
> (2) Dolor Sit

These numbers should continue to increase throughout the document, i.e. there should be no number used twice. It would behave almost like the align environment- including the possibility to `\ref` to individual lines, except that I do not wish to use it for math but rather for text snippets.

Unfortunately, I am not that LaTeX savvy, so I cannot really define such an environment myself.

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.  The non-savvy are especially welcome.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for all the answers. They are really helpful. Also, big thanks for TeX StackExchange :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for blind text
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{masterlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[masterlist]{label=(\arabic*),resume}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{masterlist}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{masterlist}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{masterlist}
\item baz
\item boo
\end{masterlist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact you want an enumerate list with number in a non default presentation. An easy way for this is the enumerate package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
  \item test1
  \item test2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the align environment (or other math-based environments) and typeset your text using `\text{...}`. Example:

```
\begin{equation}\label{mylabel}
    \text{Numbered like an equation, typeset like text.}
\end{equation}
```

Beware, though, that this is only suitable for short snippets of text, since you are, after all, inside a math environment, so there's no automatic line wrapping.

Comment: -1. This encloses text in display math mode, kludgy to say the least!  Also, equation numbers usually appear on the right, not the left.  And, this won't work for a multi-line item...`\text` will only set it as one long line.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, I agree that it's a hack, but it does satisfy Mannys requirement ("behave like align environment, except for text instead of math"). Remis solution does not support automatic numbering throughout the document. Thanks for the reminder about the multi-line thing, I've added this to my answer.

Comment: I confess I hadn't noticed numbering throughout the document was a requirement.  OK, I un-downvoted.